# Javascript checking if a string lentgh is 0 not working

Tags: javascript

I have a JS function which checks if a user entered string is zero.

```
if (str.legth = 0) {
        
            alert('Provide at least 1 character to create a folder.');
            return;

        
        
        
        
        }
```

But this seems to let a user pass a zero entered string.
Is there anything missing?

THanks

Comment: You used assignment `=`, not comparison `==`/`===`.

Answer (score 2):

You've misspelled "length" and you need "==" instead of "=" to check for equailty rather than assigning a value.

Comment: Thanks ma boy that was it

Comment: better yet using `===`  instead of `=`

Answer (score 0):

If your variable is called `str`, then length is used to return a boolean value. You need to use either `==` or `===` for an actual comparison instead of an assignment. Additionally, a `return` isn't necessary.

[image]